# JavaScript / Backbone.js layout manager

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, layout, backbone.js, layout-manager

I have a number of (Backbone.js) Controllers with a bunch of child elements.

When the browser is resized or the model changes, I'd like child elements of various controllers to be able to affect the layout of other elements.

Let's say for example that I change language in the model and that this results in my headerController => titleTextField growing from 1 to 2 rows. This should cause the container below to shrink to accomodate for the growth.

Somehow, I'd like a layout manager to be able to take this into account and reposition dependent elements accordingly.

Are there such layout managers? Alternatively how would you build one?
(Preferably one that works well with Backbone.js MVC principles)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by Controllers? Are these Backbone Controllers (which are now called Routers as of version 0.5)?  I don't understand your scenario well, but whenever possible, it's better to manage layout through CSS.

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like a CSS issue, not a javascript / mvc issue. there are plenty of css frameworks out there, such as 960grid, blueprint, and many many more, that handle this sort of layout change